# sqoop import getting hang while running MAPREDUCE job

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to import table from mysql to Sqoop. however while running the sqoop import -- the job is getting stuck in Mapreduce Job.

Please help

Code USED: 
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --direct --username=root --password= --table=authors --hive-import --hive-table=mydb.authors --target-dir=user/root/sample -m 1`

Log:

```
16/10/31 14:32:11 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `authors` AS t LIMIT 1
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `authors` AS t LIMIT 1
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/509cb57707137dd45538cf81fd7e11b1/authors.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
16/10/31 14:32:11 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/10/31 14:32:11 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `authors` AS t LIMIT 1
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `authors` AS t LIMIT 1
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
16/10/31 14:32:12 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/509cb57707137dd45538cf81fd7e11b1/authors.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/10/31 14:32:14 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/509cb57707137dd45538cf81fd7e11b1/authors.jar
16/10/31 14:32:14 INFO manager.DirectMySQLManager: Beginning mysqldump fast path import
16/10/31 14:32:14 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of authors
```

Comment: Check there is enough resources to do the job. check yarn web console

Answer (score 0):

you could create hive table before your execute the sqoop commend if you don't use `--create-hive-table` , chack your hive table exist?

eg:

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//***/orcl 
--username ***
--password ***
--table TEST
--hive-import 
--create-hive-table 
--hive-database myDB 
--hive-table table1
--hive-override
```